# learning disassembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, disassembly

In an attempt to understand what occurs underneath I am making small C programs and then reversing it, and trying to understand its objdump output.

The C program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a,b,c);
}

int main() {
    int a;
    int *ptr;

    asm("nop");
    function(1,2,3);
}
```

The objdump output for function gives me the following.

```
080483a4 <function>:
 80483a4:   55                      push   ebp
 80483a5:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80483a7:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
 80483aa:   ff 75 10                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+16]
 80483ad:   ff 75 0c                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
 80483b0:   ff 75 08                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
 80483b3:   68 04 85 04 08          push   0x8048504
 80483b8:   e8 fb fe ff ff          call   80482b8 <printf@plt>
 80483bd:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 80483c0:   c9                      leave
```

Notice that before the call to printf, three DWORD's with offsets 8,16,12(they must be the arguments to `function` in the reverse order) are being pushed onto the stack. Later a hex address which must be the address of the format string is being pushed.

`My doubt is`

1. Rather than pushing 3 DWORDS and the format specifier onto the stack directly, I expected to see the esp being manually decremented and the values being pushed onto the stack after that. How can one explain this behaviour?

Comment: The `-l` switch (that's a lowercase L) for objdump might help you; if not with this then in the future.

Comment: a push modifies esp.  Why do you expect that it should also be done explicitly?

Comment: Yep, from `push` description: "Decrements the stack pointer and then stores the source operand on the top of the stack".

Comment: This asm makes no sense. Why would the compiler push literal constants from memory rather than generating immediates? Is that C code the real source?

Comment: Yes, that is the real source code. And the compilation has been performed without optimization, perhaps that is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, some machines have a stack pointer that is kind of like any other register, so the way you push something is, yes, with a decrement followed by a store.

But some machines, like x86<sub>32/64</sub> have a *push* instruction that does a macro-op: decrementing the pointer *and* doing the store.

Macro-ops, btw, have a funny history.  At times, certain examples on certain machines have been slower than performing the elementary operations with simple instructions.

I doubt if that's frequently the case today. Modern x86 is amazingly sophisticated. The CPU will be disassembling your opcodes themselves into micro-ops which it then stores in a cache. The micro-ops have specific pipeline and time slot requirements and the end result is that there is a RISC cpu inside the x86 these days, and the whole thing goes really fast *and* has good architectural-layer code density.

Comment: There are lots of cases where using microcoded macro-ops on the x86 is much slower than breaking them down into their individual constituent ops and issuing them individually. ssqrt on the i7 is one example; it's measurably slower than using an estimated reciprocal op, followed by NR refinement and a multiply. It's because microcoded ops are not pipelined, which means that any instructions behind them have to wait for the entire macroop to finish, whether they are actually dependent or not.

Comment: That said, commonly used macro-ops (like PUSH) are indeed quite fast. But god help you if you use any of the REP string operations.

Answer (score 1):

The stack pointer is adjusted with the `push` instruction. So it's copied to `ebp` and the parameters are pushed onto the stack so they exist in 2 places each: `function`'s stack and `printf`'s stack. The `push`es affect `esp`, thus `ebp` is copied.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the info on the "-l" flag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mov [esp+x], [ebp+y] instruction, too many operands.  It would take two instructions and use a register.  Push does it in one instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard cdecl calling convention for x86 machine. There are several different types of calling conventions. You can read the following article in the Wikipedia about it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

It explains the basic principle.

Answer (score 0):

You raise an interesting point which I think has not been directly addressed so far. I suppose that you have seen assembly code which looks something like this:

```
sub esp, X
...
mov [ebp+Y], eax
call Z
```

This sort of disassembly is generated by certain compilers. What it is doing is extending the stack, then assigning the value of the new space to be `eax` (which has hopefully been populated with something meaningful by that point). This is actually equivalent to what the `push` mnemonic does. I can't answer *why* certain compilers generate this code instead but my guess is that at some point doing it this way was judged to be more efficient.

Comment: GCC does this by default. The advantage is that ESP stays the same for the whole function (disregarding calls). This is also better suited for the cdecl convention as the compiler doesn't have to adjust ESP after each call. However, the mov instructions are longer than pushes, and the difference in produced code size [can be quite significant](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0707.3/2328.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your effort to learn assembly language and disassemble binaries, you might find ODA useful.  It's a web-based disassembler, which is handy for disassembling lots of different architectures without having to build binutil's objdump for each one of them.

http://onlinedisassembler.com/